# Can we get the data from the hard disk after performing Disk Sanitizer?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, data-recovery

I accidentally press F10 4 to 5 times while the system rebooting and it gone to the Disk Sanitizer option , and the total harddisk data is erased .

When I try to install the OS again , it is showing some hard disk corruption .

Shall I get the lost data ? Any chance ?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you have erased the contents of your drive.
Using Sanitizer it is unlikely (read extremely expensive) that you will get any data back.

You could try a free tool first (http://pcsupport.about.com/od/filerecovery/tp/free-file-recovery-programs.htm) to see if you can get anything back.  Create a Boot disk (or USB stick) and grab a tool that runs off a USB stick.  Again it is unlikely.

In addition, try and identify if the drive is damaged.  If it is showing corruption along with teh lost data it may be worth checking it out.

Depending on the drive I would recommend doing a scan of the drive.  It is just not worth storing data on a drive that may not be 100%.

```
[Seagate][1]

[Western Digital][2]

[Hitachi][3]
```